# Fast Ways To Update Value in Map

Tags: algorithm, scala

I having map structure like this:

```
val map = mutable.Map[String, Double].empty
```

Than I add value to my map like this

```
map("apple") = 10.34
```

But for next value of apple I want to add to 10.34 so I doing this

```
val oldVal = map("apple")
map("apple) = oldVal + 2.34
```

Is there more faster way I can do this? Because I have to read big file and I want fast update on map. Thank you for your advices.

Comment: in place ... `map("apple") += 2.43`

Answer (score 1):

```
    val map = mutable.Map.empty[String, Double].withDefaultValue(0.0)

    //put new
    map("apple") = 10.34

    //update existing
    map("apple") += 2.34

    //update not existing
    map("orange") += 0.34
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Scala it's generally better to avoid using mutable objects. This is to avoid any issues with concurrency which is fairly simple in Scala.

If I understood your question correctly you have a map that you want to update with values. When reading from a file you could create a new map with values to add:

```
val m = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
val other = Map("a" -> 3, "c" -> 4) // created from a file
```

Now you can update the first map with values from the second map to get this:

```
val updated = m.map{ case (k, v) => { if(other.contains(k)) {(k, v + other.get(k).get)} else (k,v) }}
```

Now you can use updated to perform other operations with.